# C# XNA: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xna

I am attempting to create an asteroids game for university. However, when I am debugging the game, I keep getting an error stating that 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The line of code that the debugger states where the error is, is:

```
Asteroidorigin.X = texture.Width / 2;
Asteroidorigin.Y = texture.Height / 2;
```

Asteroidorigin and texture are defined like this:

```
public Vector2 texture;
public Vector2 Asteroidorigin;
```

The code above looks all ok to me, so any help on this matter would be appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: Probably texture is null

Comment: I'm guessing the above code should probably read: 
public Texture2D texture; // not a Vector2

Comment: yeah thats what it is supposed to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, texture has not been loaded yet. This code needs to be run after `LoadContent()` assigns that texture to an asset coming through the content pipeline.

If the code is run repeatedly, and it doesn't matter if it doesn't run the first time it is called, you could just add a null check:

```
if (texture != null)
{
    Asteroidorigin.X = texture.Width / 2;
    Asteroidorigin.Y = texture.Height / 2;
}
```

Comment: The asteroidorigin code is within an update method which is located below the LoadContent method where my texture is being loaded

Comment: Then performing the null check should be sufficient (since Update is called all the time). Just make sure anything else dependent on these properties being set is in the null check as well. If it is *always* null then make sure the load isn't failing in LoadContent

Comment: Great! When you feel this question is answered, I would appreciate you "accepting" this answer (assuming it is the best of course!)